# Laravel ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

I'm building a job marketplace similar to Elance. In the job detail page, there is proposal form also. User can fill in the form and hit submit. (Ref; former Elance job detail page)

Now, if the user want to edit their proposal data, they can hit edit for that job in their dashboard and they'll come to this job detail page again. But this time, the form will be pre-filled with data.

This is job detail method and requestdetail view @includes apply(proposal) form.

```
public function requestdetail($reqid){
if ($user = Auth::User()) {
    $gigs = Gig::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->get();
}

    $request = UserRequest::with('request_desc','user.profile')
        ->findOrFail($reqid);

    $proposals = Proposal::with('user')
        ->where('request_id','=',$reqid)
        ->orderBy("proposals.created_at","desc")
        ->get();

    return view('user.frontend.public.requestdetail',
        compact('reqid','request','proposals','gigs','countProp'));
}
```

This is the Edit Proposal method:

```
public function edit($proposalid){
    $proposal = Proposal::where('id',$proposalid)->first();
    $reqid = $proposal->request_id;
    $gigid = $proposal->gig_id;

    if ($user = Auth::User()) {
        $gigs = Gig::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->get();
    }

    $request = UserRequest::with('request_desc','user.profile')
        ->findOrFail($reqid);

    $proposals = Proposal::with('user')
        ->where('request_id','=',$reqid)
        ->orderBy("proposals.created_at","desc")
        ->get();

    return view('user.frontend.public.requestdetail',       compact('proposal','reqid','gigid','gigs','countProp','request','proposals'));
}
```

This is a field from proposal form:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <textarea id="description" value="{{ $gigid->desc }}" name="description" style="min-height:100px;" class="form-control" rows="5" required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I view the job detail page, it gives me error:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I believe, its to do the with the $gigid but how do I get around this? How do I handle the create and edit part here?

Comment: Which description are you trying to access in textarea? That for the _gig_ or for the _proposal_?

Comment: Yes, I changed to: 
value="{{ $proposal->desc?$proposal->desc:'' }}" but when I go to job detail page, now I get:  
ErrorException Undefined variable: proposal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it; adding isset() did the trick; its working perfectly. Now, my code looks like this:

```
{{ isset($proposal->deadline)?$proposal->deadline:'' }}
```

Thank you

Comment: where did you wrote that?

Comment: I put this isset() check in all fields in the proposal form. So, if its not already set then it will take ' ', and prevent "ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
$gigid = $proposal->gig_id;
```

`$gigid` contains number

so in your view:

```
$gigid->desc
```

will cause the problem. So probably instead of `$gigid` you should use other variable in your view.

Comment: Yes, I changed to: value="{{ $proposal->desc?$proposal->desc:'' }}" but when I go to job detail page, now I get: ErrorException Undefined variable: proposal

Comment: @chuck This is correct, because in your controller for `requestdetail` method you have only `$proposals` and not `$proposal`. So if you want to use it you should set this variable in controller.